# Building Assimp for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm trying to build Assimp for iOS, it compiles fine, with no errors, however, when I try to use it in my project I get a lot of errors (154 to be exact) during linking. Judging after the method signatures, the errors are C++ related, however, I would like to use the C interface. I've tested with `lipo` and the library is compiled for my arch, it's actually a fat library. They are linker errors, should be easy to fix, alas, my lack of experience doesn't help. Here is a screenshot with the errors (first rows, as there are more than 100 in total).

[image]

How should I debug this? What went wrong?

EDIT: Thanks to @Zadr I managed to narrow it down to 8 errors:

[image]

`_crc32` sounds very familiar, but still can't find the reason behind all this.

Comment: Do you link against the C++ standard library? It seems that you don't.

Comment: I though Xcode will do that for me, turns out, it linked other version (as in @zadr answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you're building was linked against one version of libstdc++, and you're trying to link against a different version.

In the project settings, there should be a "C++ standard library" field. Change that from the default option (clang's libc++, iirc) to the other option (gcc's).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You certainly put me on the right track. From 152 errors, I have 8 left. Will update the question with them.

Comment: These errors mean that the symbols aren't found. Try figuring out what library they come from. Since the names sound like they have to do with compression, its probably libz or something similar. Once you've figured that out, you can add that library as a framework to link against (Xcode -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @zadr has already mentioned, you should also link `libz.dylib` for the last 8 errors to go away. I'm *almost* certain those functions are related with it and I know for sure `Assimp` uses `libz`.

Answer (score 0):

First Tell Me if You have to Putted any `framework` as copy-paste ?? in most of cases this type of issue created.

Generally this Types of Error Occur when your class `.m` file is not store/putted under `Compile Sources`

In This case you need to add manually this `.m` file to `Compile Sources`

**Following step Describe how to put `.m` file in `Compile Sources` manually**

```
Select Project Form Project Manager
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources
                |
                |
        Click on '+' button and add .m file in it
```

This is Step For how to put file manually in `Compile Sources`.